# Display site administrator's id by current blog id inside link

Tags: multisite, admin, id

I need to add current subsite admin id on the end of the ref link.

For example 1.example.com site admin id is 4 - the link displayed on 1.example.com should look like http://example.com/?ref=4

The working code (thx to @birgire):

```
<?php
function reflink_func( $atts ){
$uids = get_users(
    array(
        'blog_id'  => get_current_blog_id(),
        'role'     => 'administrator',
        'fields'   => 'ID',
    )
);

$url = add_query_arg( 
    array( 'ref' => join( ',', $uids ) ), 
    'http://biznesvozmozhnost.ru/registration/?ref=' 
);

$link = '<a class="icallout-action btn btn-success btn-large" href="' . $url . '">Link text</a>';

return $link;
}

add_shortcode( 'reflink', 'reflink_func' );
?>
```

Comment: What if there are more than one admins per subsite?

Comment: I have only one per site, and it meant to be like this. Subsites used as a personal landing pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to construct for example:

```
http://example.com/?ref=1,8,22
```

for multiple *administrators* of the current sub site, you can try the following (untested):

```
$uids = get_users(
    array(
        'blog_id'  => get_current_blog_id(),
        'role'     => 'administrator',
        'fields'   => 'ID',
        'order_by' => 'ID',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
    )
);

echo $url = add_query_arg( 
    array( 'ref' => join( ',', $uids ) ), 
    'http://example.com' 
);
```

Comment: Checked by adding shortcode. Works like a charm. Could you tell me how to make it active link? The best to call this function from div or a tag.

Comment: Remembered that I still can do something myself (total noob). <?php
function reflink_func( $atts ){
 $uids = get_users(
    array(
        'blog_id'  => get_current_blog_id(),
        'role'     => 'administrator',
        'fields'   => 'ID',
    )
);

$url = add_query_arg( 
    array( 'ref' => join( ',', $uids ) ), 
    'http://biznesvozmozhnost.ru/registration/?ref=' 
);

$link = '<a class="reflink" href="' . $url . '">ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ В ПРОЕКТЕ</a>';

echo $link;

}
add_shortcode( 'reflink', 'reflink_func' );
?>

Comment: You should add this to your question, it's hard to read code in the comments ;-) Yes it would be handy to wrap this into a function or a shortcode.

Comment: Ah - ok. Thx I'm new to this service. Thanks A LOT for help birgire ;)

Comment: You're most welcome. ps: I see that you added the code into your question, good, but please indent it for better readability, thanx ;-) Notice that shortcode callbacks must *return* the value, not *echo* it.

Comment: Figured "return not echo" thing hard way ;) Thanks one more time. Indented the code.